# On a java TreeMap should i check size before clearing?

Tags: java

I've assumed that i can just call clear instead of

```
if (tmap.size() > 0) {
    tmap.clear();
}
```

Or is one more efficient?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: Note that "modCount" from TreeMap is not changed when doing the tmap.size() > 0 test, so this test may prevent ConcurrentModificationException in very particular cases.

Comment: I would prefer getting the ConcurrentModificationException because it highlights a fundamental problem with the usage of the map.

Comment: I'm on a time crunch and my peer believes its beneficial to check before clearing, though I'd leverage the brain power of the mighty stack overfill community to identify the best practice.

Answer (score 10):

You will gain nothing because `TreeMap.clear()` is nothing in terms of overhead :

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;
    size = 0;
    root = null;
}
```

So keep your code simple to read with just  `tmap.clear();`

JDK collections classes are written to be optimized as much as possible.
So you generally don't need to worry about basic optimizations because these are  bound to be done.
For example look at the `HashMap.clear()` logical, the `clear()` operation requires a little more overhead : clearing the table (buckets).
As a consequence, the size of the map is checked before performing that :

```
public void clear() {
    Node<K,V>[] tab;
    modCount++;
    if ((tab = table) != null && size > 0) {
        size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i)
            tab[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: And even if it did make a different, I would expect the authors of the library would then start their implementation with that `if (size() > 0)` within their implementation - so you would still be doing the right thing by just calling `clear()` ...

Comment: @moilejter It is right. JDK classes are designed to be efficiently written.